# WPF: Animation - accessing a Button background brush from code behind for animations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, background

I am attempting to animate a button's background color when it is clicked.

I am running into an issue actually grabbing the Brush that defines the button's background so I can animate it.  It is a linearGradientBrush.

The issue I am running into is that I cannot figure out a way to actually animate the color.  When the storyboard begins, it throws an error telling me "Cannot animate '(0)' on an immutable object instance".

In addition to this, I believe I'm not doing this correctly.  The end result is to animate the background from it's current color to Red and back until some condition is met.

The overall question would be...is my approach correct?  Is there a better way to animate a button's background color?

```
private void RoundedButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //THIS OBVIOUSLY WON'T WORK BUT GIVES AN IDEA OF WHAT I'M TRYING TO ACCOMPLISH
    LinearGradientBrush recBrush =   ((SharedLibrary.Wpf.Controls.RoundedButton)sender).Background as LinearGradientBrush;

    ColorAnimation pulserAnimation = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Red, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)));
    pulserAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
    pulserAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

    Storyboard.SetTarget(pulserAnimation, recBrush);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(pulserAnimation, new    PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

    //Add the animations to the new Storyboard
    sb.Children.Add(pulserAnimation);

    //run the animation
    sb.Begin();
}
```

Comment: "I am running into an issue actually grabbing the Brush..."  What is the issue that you are running into?

Comment: I'll update the code.  It should be a LinearGradientBrush instead of SolidColorBrush.

Comment: That still doesn't tell us what "running into an issue" means.  What is the exact issue that you are having?

Comment: Strange...part of my post got clipped.  I will update sorry.

Comment: Post updated...basically I believe my approach is wrong but I can't see a better way to animate a button background and still be able to STOP the animation to revert back to it's original background